# android - Using custom layout throws InflateException causing app to force close

Tags: android, layout

I am using Eclipse and created HelloWorld and it works fine using emulator.
Then I tried to create ToDoList app where you can enter text and click to submit, following the example on the book I have and getting an error that cause my app to force close when I interact with the application.

my directory structure: (please ignore other folders)

```
ProjectToDoList
   |
   |-----src
   |      |----com.test.dotolist
   |                          |------ToDoList.java
   |                          |------ToDoListItemView.java
   ------res
          |
          |----layout
                 |-------main.xml
                 |-------todolist_item.xml
```

I tracked where it is happening:

If I just use default layout in ToDoList.java like:

```
 final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
 final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
 aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, todoItems);
```

The app works fine. I can type in text and click a button for the text to show up.

But I'm trying to use my custom layout:

ToDoList.java,

```
        final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        int resID = R.layout.todolist_item;

        //create array adopter to bind the array to the listview
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, resID, todoItems);

        //bind the array adapter to the listview
        myListView.setAdapter(aa);
```

As you can see when I try to pass resID to ArrayAdapter, it compile and my app shows up on the emulator. But when I click submit button, it force to close.

todoList_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.test.todolist.ToDoListItemView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/notepad_text"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"    
/>
```

The logcat output: (I can't figure out what's wrong)

```
W/KeyCharacterMap(  279): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
D/AndroidRuntime(  279): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  279): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  279): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.test.todolist.ToDoListItemView
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.todolist.ToDoListItemView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.test.dotolist-1.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
E/AndroidRuntime(  279):    ... 32 more
W/ActivityManager(   66):   Force finishing activity com.test.dotolist/.ToDoList
```

Please let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: class ToDoListItemView is extended as???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your Exception::

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.todolist.ToDoListItemView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.test.dotolist-1.apk]
```

and see your Package::

```
ProjectToDoList
   |
   |-----src
   |      |----com.test.dotolist
   |                          |------ToDoListItemView.java
```

**todolist != dotolist**

you have in your todoList_item.xml

```
<com.test.todolist.ToDoListItemView
```

Change to::

```
<com.test.dotolist.ToDoListItemView
```

this must work! =)

Comment: hmm... could you explain more? It seems like ToDoListItemView class is not found?

Comment: Yep it worked! It was typo in the package name like you pointed out and I also had to change the package element in manifest.xml too. I feel like an idiot..stack this issue for several hours... thanks again :)